# celebrated Lindeberg condition

Tags: statistics

Lindeberg-Feller CLT is Theorem 4.12 in Foundations of Modern Probability by Olav Kallenberg
that says

Let $ (ξn,j;j=1,…,n)^∞_{n=1}$
be a triangular array of row-wise independent random variables with mean $ 0$
and $\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\xi_{nj}^2] \to 1$
as $n→∞$
.

Suppose that for any ϵ>0
we have $ ∑_j E[ξ^2_{nj}  ;|ξ_{nj} |>ε]→0 $ for all $ ε>0 $  (celebrated Lindeberg condition)
.

Then$ \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_{n,j} \overset{d}{\to} N(0,1)$
.

from the definitions of book if (Ω,A,P) be the probability space

$E[ξ  ;a]=∫_a ξ dp $ where $a ∈ A$

but I don't understand how  $|ξ_{ni} |>ε$ can be our events.

if
$ \\ξ_{n,j} = \frac{X_j - \mu_j}{\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i^2}} $
how we can show that condition holds ?

Comment: The event "$| \xi_{ni} |> \varepsilon$" in the conditional expectation is $ \{  \omega \in \Omega  : | \xi_{ni} (\omega)|  >\varepsilon \}$.

Comment: @jd27 is   |   |   cardinality or  absolute value ?

Comment: it is the absolute value